# bash: grep pattern from file and count different options

Tags: bash

I have a txt file that has multiple lines of the following structure:

```
@HISEQ:XXX:8:1101:11058:2481 1:N:0:ATTCCTTTTCTTTCCC
@HISEQ:XXX:8:1101:11009:2489 1:N:0:ATCACGATTATTTCCC
@HISEQ:XXX:8:1101:1414:2364 1:N:0:GCCAATATCCTTTCCC
@HISEQ:XXX:8:1101:11009:2489 1:N:0:ATCACGATTATTTCCC
```

Now I want to grep the pattern behind the last ':'

In this case it would be:

```
ATTCCTTTTCTTTCCC
ATCACGATTATTTCCC
GCCAATATCCTTTCCC
ATCACGATTATTTCCC
```

I then want to count the number of times each of those patterns was found.

So something like this:

```
ATTCCTTTTCTTTCCC: 1
ATCACGATTATTTCCC: 2
GCCAATATCCTTTCCC: 1
```

Can this be done with bash?

Comment: add some examples, what u want to receive.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk -F: '{print $NF; tok[$NF]++} END {
   print "==== Uniques ==="; for (i in tok) print i, tok[i]}' file

ATTCCTTTTCTTTCCC
ATCACGATTATTTCCC
GCCAATATCCTTTCCC
ATCACGATTATTTCCC
==== Uniques ===
ATTCCTTTTCTTTCCC 1
GCCAATATCCTTTCCC 1
ATCACGATTATTTCCC 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to remove everything before `:`, then sort with uniq to count the occurences:

```
sed 's/.*://' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat filename|cut -d':' -f9|sort|uniq -c`